# Firefox tells user they need a plugin to display an embedded webpage

Tags: html, firefox, embed

There's a section on my site where I display data from another site, using:

```
<embed src="URL"></embed>
```

I recently discovered that this works fine for most people, but that Firefox users get an error telling them they need to install a plugin. I searched around for a solution and people seemed to find that specifying the MIME type worked:

```
<embed type="text/html" src="URL"></embed>
```

But this isn't working. I can switch to iFrames, but I dislike how they display the information. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What's the difference of `<embed />` and `<iframe></iframe>`? In Chrome it looks the same.

Comment: Not that this helps with your problem, but embed is a void element. No `</embed>` needed or desired! Anyway, are you sure that switching to an iframe really works, that it isn't some content inside the embedded html file that is triggering the warning?

Comment: The site I'm embedding is a partial Google Doc, and when I used the iframe link Google gave me for embedding, it came with an annoying info border. It looks like I can solve the problem by using the link I was using with <embed> and just replacing that tag with <iframe> instead. Nevertheless, I'm curious why <embed> doesn't work, and just in Firefox. It seems like it should! (Also, thanks for the tip, Mr Lister; I actually didn't have the </embed> tag before and then saw others doing it and thought it was unnecessary but preferred!)

Answer (score 1):

Per spec, `embed` elements are only handled via plug-ins or an SVG renderer (and in the latter case behave just like `iframe`).

You can do `<object data="URL"></object>`, but of course that will *also* behave like iframe...

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with an html5 game.  It appears that Firefox doesn't support  if you want to embed an external html file.  This tag should only be used for plugins.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

To embed an external html file into another page in Firefox you have to use iframe or object tags instead.  For the interactive nature of my external page I used iframe and it worked in IE / Chrome and FF, I had to make the margins larger than the game itself.